# Как работает git stash?И почему git не дает мне переключить ветку после коммита

Tags: git

Никак не понимаю почему git не дает мне переключить ветку.

Сделал

```
git add .
git commit -m "bla bla"
```

И когда нужно переключить ветку выдает ошибку:

```
local changes would be overwritten by checkout
```

Но почему? Я же сделал коммит?

Не понимаю как работает `git stash`, но попробовал и его.
До переключение пишу

```
git stash
```

Потом переключил в ветку master

Сделал свои дела потом обратно в свою ветку

Пишу

```
git stash pop
```

И

```
git merge master
```

Опять ошибка

```
Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge
```

Так в чем проблема?

Comment: попробуйте поменять команды `git merge master` и `git stash pop` местами. git stash сохраняет Ваши изменения в локальное хранилище-стек, а pop достает их. Когда Вы мержите две ветки и файлы текущей модифицированы, а в другой ветки они обновлились, то и будет такая ошибки.

Comment: @KoVadim сделал так как вы написали не сработало.cmd показал имя файла:  needs merge. Но изменения которое я сделал не вернулись

Comment: "needs merge" - ожидаемо. Поэтому и предыдущее сообщение получали. устраняйте конфликт и делайте новый коммит. А пока не решите конфликт (или не отмените мерж), гит будет потихоньку сопротивлятся

Comment: @KoVadim так я с начало устранил конфликты потом, написал git stash pop и получил сообщение про needs merge. Конфликтов больше нет.

Comment: и это ожидаемо - файл то поменялся. А вернуть назад с  stash - это как сделать мерж. Да, нужно будет снова решать конфликт.

Comment: @KoVadim но конфликтов нету, что мне решить?) Просто имя файла и needs merge

Comment: открываете этот файл в любом редакторе и ищите строку `<<<<<<<` и решаете конфликт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в файле `.eslintignore`.

Было настройка если хотя бы есть один *eslint warning* то делать `push` либо `commit` не получиться.

Поэтому мои `commit`-ы на самом деле не работали.

Также в файле `.eslintignore` были имена папок которое не показывали те папки и файлы в котором есть eslint warning.

После очистки этого файла и удаления всех предупреждений все заработало.